# Using JSON variables later in JSON file

Tags: json, constants

I'm using JSON in a project where certain groups of values can appear in the JSON file quite often. Therefore, I was hoping to be able to define them at the top or in a Constants.JSON file, and then simply reference them wherever they are used. How would I go about doing that in the JSON files? for example:

```
"allowableVales":{"values"=strSABValues}
```

where strSABValues would be a JSON array defined earlier in the file. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Json is not a programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of a "JSON variable" is inherently misguided as JSON is not a programming langauge. It's nothing more than a formatted string, in fact.

One way you could achieve something like this is to use a specific format for a property value that your javascript would know to interpret as needing to look elsewhere for that value, but it wouldn't really be a variable in a literal sense.

Something like this (although it's probably more trouble than it's worth):

```
var data = {
    "rootvalue": "hello",
    "values": {
        "value1": "goodbye",
        "value2": "{rootvalue}"
    }
}

if (data["values"]["value2"] == "{rootvalue}") {
   var realvalue = data["rootvalue"];
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/WxYzZ/)

Answer (score 1):

You could write it as a string and use the eval() function when you reference it. So, your JSON entry would be:

```
"allowableVales":{"values"="strSABValues"}
```

Then, when you actually import the JSON later on, say in JavaScript, you can write:

```
const strSABValues = ['A','B'];
console.log('The allowable values are ' + eval(allowableVales.values));
```